# How to append data to file using file_put_contents()?

Tags: php, android, loops, foreach

I have an  android app that sends multiple data from okhttp3 but i can't find a way to log all the data sent in php..My current log only houses the last record(Show below). My best guess is that the php file data is being overwritten until the last record..How can I log all the data sent? And yes all the data is being sent out from the android app...

index.php

```
if (isset($_POST))
 {
file_put_contents("post.log",print_r($_POST,true));
}
```

Sample post.log

```
 Array
(
    [date] =>  02 Aug, 12:22
    [company] => Assert Ventures
    [lattitude] => 32.8937542
    [longitude] => -108.336584
    [user_id] => Malboro
    [photo_id] => 1
)
```

What I want

```
(
   [date] =>  02 Aug, 12:22
   [company] => Three Ventures
   [lattitude] => 302.8937542
   [longitude] => -55.336584
   [user_id] => Malboro
   [photo_id] => 1
),
(
   [date] =>  02 Aug, 12:22
   [company] => Two Ventures
   [lattitude] => 153.8937542
   [longitude] => -88.336584
   [user_id] => Malboro
   [photo_id] => 1
),
(
    [date] =>  02 Aug, 12:22
    [company] => Assert Ventures
    [lattitude] => 32.8937542
    [longitude] => -108.336584
    [user_id] => Malboro
    [photo_id] => 1
)
```

Comment: how have you used fopen (w or a mode)?

Comment: @coder he hasn't see `file_put_contents()`

Comment: @coder no need to..file_put_contents 'fopens', 'fwrites' and  'fcloses' by default

Comment: @RiggsFolly  my bad

Comment: @Aeonia In future [**RT?M** its all in there](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Will do..Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to pass third parameter `FILE_APPEND`;

So your PHP code will look something like this,

```
if (isset($_POST))
 {
file_put_contents("post.log",print_r($_POST,true),FILE_APPEND);
}
```

> **FILE_APPEND** flag helps to append the content to the end of the
>   file instead of overriding the content.

Comment: Worked perfectly..Thanks

Comment: @Aeonia don't forget to select Alok's answer since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 10):

I think you should add FILE_APPEND flag.

```
<?php
$file = 'post.log';
// Add data to the file
$addData = print_r($_POST,true);
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $addData, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```