# Mutiple file_put_content not working except the last one

Tags: php

I have a file `data.php` looks like the below:

```
$first_data = 0;
$second_data = 0;
$third_data = 0;
```

I have three HTML checkbox on frontend and I would like to store the value into `data.php`.

( The value is `1` if it's checked )

In `process.php`, I use `$_POST['data_value']` and store the value into the variables which looks like the below:

```
$process_first_data = isset ( $_POST['first_checkbox'] ) ? 1 : 0;
$process_second_data = isset ( $_POST['second_checkbox'] ) ? 1 : 0;
$process_third_data = isset ( $_POST['third_checkbox'] ) ? 1 : 0;
```

And I use this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574999/replacing-file-content-in-php/3575012#3575012) with `preg_replace` to replace the value in `data.php` from `process.php` which looks like the below:

```
$find_first_data = '/\$first_data = \d;/';
$find_second_data = '/\$second_data = \d;/';
$find_third_data = '/\$third_data = \d;/';

$replace_first_data = '$first_data = ' . $process_first_data . ';';
$replace_second_data = '$second_data = ' . $process_second_data . ';';
$replace_third_data = '$third_data = ' . $process_third_data . ';';

$dir = 'path/to/file';
$file_content = file_get_contents ( $dir );

file_put_contents ( $dir, preg_replace ( $find_first_data, $replace_first_data, $file_content ) );
file_put_contents ( $dir, preg_replace ( $find_second_data, $replace_second_data, $file_content ) );
file_put_contents ( $dir, preg_replace ( $find_third_data, $replace_third_data, $file_content ) );
```

But now the problem is only the last `file_put_contents` is working. For example, now only the third one is working. And if I remove the third one, there are two left, then the second one is working only. And if I remove the second and the third one, there is one left, then the first one is working only.

There is no error, sorry for the long story because I want to make it in detail. May I know why only the last `file_put_contents` is working in this case?

Comment: If you are using $dir for the filename each time then it will overwrite the previous file, do you want to append to the end of the file if it exists?

Comment: If you want to write at the end of file use flags  `FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX` . `FILE_APPEND` will write at end , `LOCK_EX` will  prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append data to file using file\_put\_contents()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852041/how-to-append-data-to-file-using-file-put-contents)

Comment: @leighboz Hi, I don't want to append to the end because I want to replace the existing one, that's the reason I'm using `preg_replace`. May I know if there is there any solution for this?

Comment: @angel.bonev Hi, I think `FILE_APPEND` is not suitable for my case, would `LOCK_EX` work if I want to replace the existing ones instead of appending them to the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to understand code better is to introduce some meaningful names for intermediate variables. So we could change this:

```
$dir = 'path/to/file';
$file_content = file_get_contents ( $dir );

file_put_contents ( $dir, preg_replace ( $find_first_data, $replace_first_data, $file_content ) );
file_put_contents ( $dir, preg_replace ( $find_second_data, $replace_second_data, $file_content ) );
file_put_contents ( $dir, preg_replace ( $find_third_data, $replace_third_data, $file_content ) );
```

To this:

```
$dir = 'path/to/file';
$original_file_content = file_get_contents ( $dir );

$first_new_content = preg_replace ( $find_first_data, $replace_first_data, $original_file_content );
file_put_contents ( $dir, $first_new_content );

$second_new_content = preg_replace($find_second_data, $replace_second_data, $original_file_content );
file_put_contents ( $dir, $second_new_content);

$third_new_content = preg_replace($find_third_data, $replace_third_data, $original_file_content );
file_put_contents ( $dir, $third_new_content);
```

Now, notice that the definitions for the three new variables don't reference each other, or re-read the file, they just look at `$original_file_content`. They could actually happen in any order, before the set of `file_put_contents` calls:

```
$dir = 'path/to/file';
$original_file_content = file_get_contents ( $dir );

$third_new_content = preg_replace($find_third_data, $replace_third_data, $original_file_content );
$second_new_content = preg_replace($find_second_data, $replace_second_data, $original_file_content );
$first_new_content = preg_replace ( $find_first_data, $replace_first_data, $original_file_content );

file_put_contents ( $dir, $first_new_content);
file_put_contents ( $dir, $second_new_content);
file_put_contents ( $dir, $third_new_content);
```

Since `file_put_contents` *over-writes the whole file by default*, the content of the file will always be `$third_new_content`.

What you probably intended is for each of the replacements to happen on the result of the previous one, then write the final result to the file at the end:

```
$dir = 'path/to/file';
$original_file_content = file_get_contents ( $dir );

$first_new_content = preg_replace ( $find_first_data, $replace_first_data, $original_file_content );
$second_new_content = preg_replace($find_second_data, $replace_second_data, $first_new_content );
$third_new_content = preg_replace($find_third_data, $replace_third_data, $second_new_content );

file_put_contents ( $dir, $third_new_content);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all three file_put_contents() are working, but you are overwriting the same file "$dir" three times.

file_put_contents($file, $contents, $flags);

An example of $flags is FILE_APPEND which will append to the end of the file instead of overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FILE_APPEND` option

e.g.

```
file_put_contents ( $dir, preg_replace ( $find_third_data, $replace_third_data, $file_content ), FILE_APPEND );
```